# Exporting DB from android device sd can't write

Tags: android, sqlite, export

Hello I have this code

```
public void onbtnExportDBToPCClick(View view){

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), data.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//"+data+"//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//"+"cDataBase.db";
            String backupDBPath = "//backupcDataBase.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), currentDBPath.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

   }
```

I have set permitions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" > </uses-permission>
```

but code stops at   if (sd.canWrite()) it does not go further. I don't know what is the problem. What else should I have to set?

Comment: Is the external storage card your own? Or are you trying to write to the device storage?

Comment: I am trying on the emulator to do it

Comment: I am not very familiar with the emulator, but there may be some sort of alternate option in Android Studio that allows you to provision x MB for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, as the sd.canWrite() condition evaluates to false, that would lead one to believe that the sd card is inaccessible. Have you tried testing an android device and viewing the Logcat for output?

Comment: no I don't have a phone to try

Comment: ok. See the edited part of my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html) will help clear some things up.

You need to provision sd card space on your virtual disk image using the terminal provided in android studio.

The basic shell command seems to be something along these lines:

```
mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img
```

EDIT:

Or, if you're not comfortable in the shell just go to your AVD manager and edit your emulator's advanced settings. I think the option is something like sd card and then select studio managed, and then provision X mb of memory.